# What would be correct "Businessman's club" or "Businessmen's club"?

Tags: british-english, possessives

What would be correct "Businessman's club" or "Businessmen's club"? If there is a difference, British version.

(just in case, or "Businessman club" or "Businessmen club" or any other forms?)

Comment: One is singular and one is plural. Which one is correct would depend on context.

Comment: Can you tell us the context that you want to use this phrase.  Are you planning to start a club?  Are you writing a story?  Is there some other context?

Comment: This [Ngram look-up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=businessman%27s+club%2Cbusinessmen%27s+club&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbusinessman%20%27s%20club%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbusinessmen%20%27s%20club%3B%2Cc0) shows "businessmen's club" is preferred

Answer (score 1):

Probably "Businessmen's club" is better. This, I assume, is a club that exists to provide social activities to many businessmen, rather than a club owned by a particular businessman. Hence the plural is better.

A brief internet search find both forms in use, but the plural seems to be more common.  However most of the results are about "Legitimate businessmen's club" as a comically obvious euphemism for a mafia.

So use with caution.